# Difference between stack/unstack, shape and pivot in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am pretty new to python and I am starting to read up on big data analysis using pandas.

I was given the task of getting the following table from long form into tall form

```
    Pick 'n Pay Woolworths  Spar        Checkers    Friendly 7
0   22.222222   11.111111   44.444444   NaN         NaN
1   8.333333    5.555556    8.333333    11.111111   33.333333
2   8.982036    7.185629    11.976048   35.928144   NaN
3   12.500000   37.500000   37.500000   12.500000   NaN
```

My initial thoughts were that I should use reshaping, but eventually I settled on using `df.stack()`.

This brought the question to the forefront of my mind: what is the difference between stacking/unstacking, reshaping and pivoting? Which situation should each be used in?

Answer (score 0):

(default level is the innermost level)
stack - transfering the column to row 
unstack - transfering the row to column